# Use Kendo UI Editor without html

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-editor

I'm trying to figure out how I can user the kendo editor so that the text I insert is not encoded as html when I send it to the controller but just normal text. I have a custom toolbar I need thats why I cannot just simply use a textarea. Any ideas how to achive this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/editor---remove-html-tags-for-reporting)?

Comment: Yes, but it doesnt work the way I want. I switched now to a normal textArea.. I Think there is really not a good solution yet.

Comment: Can you post your editor definition code?